# BBC basic variables

Tags: basic

Background info for the problem: I am writing a text adventure game where the player has multiple paths to choose at each intersection/ problem.

Problem: I am attempting to use a variable from another path, which may not of been called upon. Is there anyway to call this variable before or skip a line of code?

This is the section of my code I am talking about

```
   38     input "What do you do? 'A' to continue, 'B' to run away" , BAB$
   39     if BAB$ == "A" then
   40       if BCP$ == "B" then
   41         print "The hunters see you return"
   42         print "When they ask if you found the prisoner, you respond by saying that you havent seen him"
   43         print "The hunters decide that this venture isnt worth it, and decide to leave, taking you with them"
   44         wait 30
   45         print "You escape shortly after the rest of the group leaves the area"
   46         print "You are now a free man"
   47         wait 200
   48         clear
   49         cls
   50         goto 100
   51       else
   52         goto 55
   53       endif
```

Have any questions about my wording? Just ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer to this question is to just initialise the variable at the start of the program:

```
BAB$ = ""
BCP$ = ""
```

That way, when you hit line 40, either BCP$ will have a value of "" or have a value of something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me a bunch! Saved me from hours of worrying about what I could of done wrong

Comment: When you get a bit more familar with this - look up procedures and functions (if you're using BBC basic) as this will make your code clearer with a lot less of those pesky GOTOs.

Comment: @Justin Given the nature of the programs this is risky advice on its own because GOTO is different from calling a procedure. GOTO is used to go from one room/place to the next in a text adventure here. You don't want to use a procedure call to go to another room and allocate more and more stack space on each room change. ON … PROC that dispatches on a room/place number to procedures in some sort of main game loop would be a way to model rooms with procedures.

Comment: @BlackJack You're right, but from a programming perspective one really needs to get out of the GOTO habit. Using GOTOs or worse, their GOSUB brethren, makes debugging programs a lot more difficult.  I know this is mainly personal opinion,  I stopped using GOTOs in BBC BASIC as soon as I learnt about procedures and functions. That said, its been a good 20 or so years since I've coded in anger with BBC BASIC so I've probably forgotten a lot of stuff about it!

Comment: Yes I would also try to get rid of GOTOs but not with PROC/FN because those are replacements for GOSUB. GOTOs usually are a case for structured IF and loops. They can be replaced with PROC/FN sometimes if the language allows PROC/FN as values. This depends on the version of BBC BASIC used. The classic ones AFAIK don't have this feature. The DOS versions and later have indirect calls and PROC/FN values as arguments.